# Sending checkBox value to access database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

I have an Access database. I'm creating a Winforms application to manage it. So I've made this form which allows the user to make a new entry into the database. I've successfully gotten it to pass text values from text boxes into the database, however I'm stuck when it comes to checkboxes.

There is a column in my table in my Access database called 'LABEL' which is a Yes/No field. I need to append to that field the status of the checkBox.

This is my code so far and I'm thinking about how I can implement this.

```
private void btn_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "insert into COMPUTERS (PCNAME, PROCESSOR, DRIVE, RAM, COMMENT, YEAR_MADE, LOC_SITE, CONS_DATA, OLD_ID, TYPE, COMPANY, DONOR, LOCATION, LABEL) values('"+ txt_PCName.Text + "', '"+ txt_Processor.Text+ "', '" + txt_Drive.Text + "','" + txt_RAM.Text + "', '" + txt_Comment.Text + "', '" + txt_Year.Text + "', '" + txt_LocSite.Text + "', '" + txt_ConData.Text + "', '" + txt_OldID.Text + "','" + comboBoxType.Text + "','" + comboBoxCompany.Text + "','" + comboBoxDonor.Text + "','" + comboBoxLocation.Text + "')";

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Καταχώρηση επιτυχής.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex);
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

I'd like to add it to the current query if possible.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if the code is sloppy, beginner stuff.

Comment: Use Command Parameter to define the values and type of the data you're about to store. A CheckBox value is a `bool`, a `Yes/No` Field is a `bool`. Just store the current `Checked` status of the CheckBox. Using [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter). Note that Access parameters are positional, not named (you can simply use `?` as placeholder): only the order in which you add them is considered.

Answer (score 0):

checkbox has Checked property who returns true or false whether its checked or not

so you can declare a variable like below:
string label= "No";
if(checkbox12.Checked)
label= "Yes";

OR
label = checkbox12.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
the you could use this variable in your query

Comment: Thank you, I actually thought about doing this! I'm just stuck at the part where I need to pass this value onto my database and how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use string concatenation as a way of constructing queries. It leaves your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, as well as Syntax errors in your query if the values are unfortunate.

The safer way is to use parameters. When you do this, you can think about the type of your parameters. The checkbox has a `Checked` property indicating whether it is checked, or if it is a "three-way" checkbox, then you'll need to use `CheckState`.

Also note that your command is `IDisposable`, so should be in a `using` block.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not really worried about SQL injection attacks for this project and am not interested in switching to using parameters right now.

Comment: @myrtillobruh OK, then you should try inserting a value where the Donor is `O'Reilly`...